# X before the date in xts time series

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have these 2 columns in 1 column I have the date and time and the other column reading of the device.
I am using xts to convert the time series into xts object but after converting I am not able to plot the time series and I am getting x before the date. and the error 'x' must be a time-series object. i have even used as.POSIXct(x, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS") but still I am getting an error.

X2020.10.13.09.54.00
0.165
X2020.10.13.09.54.30
0.166
X2020.10.13.09.55.00
0.166
X2020.10.13.09.55.30
0.166
X2020.10.13.09.56.00
0.166
X2020.10.13.09.56.30
0.166
X2020.10.13.09.57.00
0.166
X2020.10.13.09.57.30
0.166
X2020.10.13.09.58.00
0.166
X2020.10.13.09.58.30
0.166
X2020.10.13.09.59.00
0.166

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I have figured it out. I still have X in my View data but the error ' the error 'x' must be a time-series object' is gone. The problem was my numbers were in character form. So, I have converted them to numeric form and now I am able to have time series and plots.